Reading data from cds in python
I have downloaded data from cds (in netcdf format) and I try to read them with python.
Code
print(os.path.exists('H:/..../input/cds/adaptor.mars.internal-1724917213.28164-23661-3-f41a1d6b-53a1-404b-a286-0bb450d62874.nc'))  # This should return True if the file exists

dataset = nc.Dataset('H:/..../input/cds/adaptor.mars.internal-1724917213.28164-23661-3-f41a1d6b-53a1-404b-a286-0bb450d62874.nc', mode='r')

Output
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
Cell In[4], line 3
dataset = nc.Dataset('H:/...../input/cds/adaptor.mars.internal-1724917213.28164-23661-3-f41a1d6b-53a1-404b-a286-0bb450d62874.nc', mode='r')
File src\netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx:2470 in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.init
File src\netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx:2107 in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:/..../input/cds/adaptor.mars.internal-1724917213.28164-23661-3-f41a1d6b-53a1-404b-a286-0bb450d62874.nc'
Although the os.path returns true, I get a file not found error.
